# What's the efficiency of this program?

Tags: java, arrays, big-o

What's the efficiency (in Big O notation) of a simple program that traverses a 2D array of ints and outputs each element.

Take the following code as an example:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   int[] array = {{1,2,3,4},
                  {5,6,7,8},
                  {9,10,11,12},
                  {13,14,15,16}};

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
       {
          System.out.println(array[i][j]);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: i think its O(n) (linear time) since we're progressing through each of the arrays elements only once.  However, I have another more authoritative source that claims the snippet runs in quadratic (On^2) time since there are there is one nested loop.

Comment: @tomejuan It can't be linear! You have a loop nested inside the other

Comment: To some extent it's a question of what we're counting; if we are counting the number of vectors, yeah.

Comment: Since no one can agree, I'm upvoting the question.

Comment: @george it does run in linear time, the performance of the program is directly proportional to the number of elements in the data set.

Comment: @tomejuan, George is right: you're doing access operations on each element of the vectors.  So you have O(n) vector operations, O(m) scalars on each vector, and O(nm) overall.

Comment: How do you define your n? If n is the size of the array and not the elements then it is not linear

Comment: @FarmBoy: The only reason no-one can agree is because it's not clear what `n` is.  Once that's known, the answer is obviously trivial.

Comment: @George Kastrinis Just because you have several nested loops doesn't mean the result can't be linear or even sublinear. I've seen that claim often enough to think it's important to note that such a simplification really won't work. If we define N as the number of elements in the whole array voila we've turned the problem into a linear solution.

Comment: @Voo I already replied to that.

Comment: You're all forgetting that the input size is completely fixed (constant). This algorithm is clearly O(1).

Answer (score 14):

O (n*m) where n the number of arrays (first dimenstion) and m the max size of each internal array (second dimension)

Answer (score 7):

I'd even note that the size of *m* is comparable to the size of *n* and make this *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Comment: I'm going with this one, since Big O notation is supposed to describe *worst case performance.*  See the O(N^2) example here: http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: By referring to the definition, it's straightforward to show that *O(nm)* == *O(n^2)* anyway, in the sense in which "==" is interpreted with asumptotic notation.

Comment: Hey, I left in the point that SO won't accept <sup> tags in comments on purpose.

Comment: @Charlie: If you think it's important, bring it up on the [meta site.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) However, it's likely that it's been discussed there already.

Comment: @Robert: Big-O notation does *not* denote worst-case analysis; it can be used to describe best-case, average-case or worst-case (or anything else), depending on the context.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Well but nobody stops you from making m >> n in which case the simplification won't work. So without further information simplifying it to O(n^2) can backfire..

Comment: @Oli: In *this context,* it is O(n^2).  To be clearer, Big O notation is supposed to tell you what a reasonable expectation for performance is.

Comment: @Robert: Indeed.  I was just contesting the claim (which your linked article incorrectly makes) that by definition, big-O describes worst-case.

Comment: @Voo, let's assume that m >> n, but that m is not a function of n.  There exists some m that is the longest vector, and we know from the for loop that n is fixed.  So we know that m/n is some well-defined constant, call it k.  So we have O((k*n)*n), which is O(k*(n*n)) but by definition since k is a constant, that's equivalent to O(n*n) and thus O(n^2).

Comment: @Charlie: "m is not a function of n" contradicts "we know that m/n is some well-defined constant"!

Comment: @Charlie I don't see how you can specify that m/n is a well defined constant for every possible input? Assume that both m and n depend on some k with n = k and m = 10^k. So if we substitute m and n in O(m*n) with k we get O(10^k) which is exponential. If we beforehand simplify it to O(n^2) we get O(k^2) which is only polynomial. And clearly O(10^k) != O(k^2).

Comment: -1 unfortunately: O(n^2) is extrapolation based on observation of this particular dataset.

Comment: @Voo, that would contradict the assumption I made.  It is therefore no particularly great surprise that you can arrive at a spurious other result. @Oli, don't be a fool: we're looking at a *particular* program for which we're trying to get an asymptotic bound on the run-time.  This *particular* program is operating on nested arrays, for which there is *some* upper bound on the length.  The argument then follows.  On the other hand, you're right I could have been more precise by saying m is not a non-linear function of n; I thought that was obvious when I wrote it.

Comment: @Charlie: No need to resort to that kind of talk.  As has been pointed out, there is nothing here that implies any kind of dependency between `m` and `n`.  Your answer assumes that there is.

Comment: @Oli, if you can't cope with the math you can't.  But the argument doesn't depend on any particular relationship between m and n except that the magnitude of m and n being fixed at the time of the program running, which this clearly is.  Let's say that m were >> n.  Then the same argument would give us the asymptotic result that it's O(m^2), which is isomorphic to O(n^2) up to renaming. I know order stantistics can be confusing, but work through it from the definition and you'll see it.

Comment: @Charlie: Your argument necessarily relies on an assumption that m = kn (+ lower-order terms), where k is a constant for all possible input sets (i.e. k is not a function of n). Clearly m and n are fixed at compile-time; I'm not sure why that should make a difference.  So I don't have a problem with the maths; if your initial assumption is valid, then I agree with your conclusion. If it's not, then I don't. (And what do order statistics have to do with it?)

Answer (score 4):

Considering that your algorithm visits every element in the array once, it is `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the 2D array.

Comment: No, because the lists are significant; it's *O(nm)* or even *O(n^s)*.

Comment: +1: I don't know why this is being downvoted; it's a valid answer.  If there are `n` elements in total, we visit each one once; thus this is `O(n)`.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "n". It's not an unreasonable view to say "n" is the total number of elements.

Comment: @Charie Martin, this is precisely why I stated *where `n` is ...*. We could have said it's `O(rc)` or `O(p)` where `p = r * c`; it's the same thing - this algorithm is linear to the number of total elements in the 2d array. Which is another way of saying the number of rows times the number of columns. These are identical answers.

Answer (score 4):

Since you traverse each element in the matrix once, it is O(nm), where n is the number of rows, and m is the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

It will take O(n) because this algorithm will take the same time if you put the same number of elements into a one-dimensional array and iterate through it in a single loop.

Answer (score -1):

This is O(n^2) since the inner loop is dependent on the outside loop.  O(n*m) rarely describes runtime of loops - that is used for graphs.  Eg: O(V+E) vertices and edges.

Comment: So you'd say that a 2d array with 2 arrays that are both 10E100 elements long is limited by the length of the 2d array ie 2? That I pretty much doubt. There's no formal definition that limits m <~ n so you can't just assume n ~ m